# php display default images if no record in mysql

Tags: php

I got below php code to search and display images from mysql, it's working fine so far, i want to add a feature to display a default images if the search result got no record found in mysql ($field5name).

I have tried to add an 'onerror' function inside  but not working, what is missing from my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <body>
    <!-- [SEARCH FORM] -->
    <form method="post" action="1-form.php">
      <h1>SEARCH FOR USERS</h1>
      <input type="text" name="search" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </form>
<br/>
<div align="left"><Font size="4"><a href="logout.php" style="margin-right:80px;">LOGOUT</a></font></div><br>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    require "2-search.php";
    echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"> 
      <tr> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">ID</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">OTP</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">EMAIL</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">STATUS</font> </td> 
          <td> <font face="Arial">TIMESTAMP</font> </td> 
      </tr>';
    // DISPLAY RESULTS
    if (count($results) > 0) {
        foreach ($results as $r) {
            $field1name = $r["id"];
            $field2name = $r["otp"];
            $field3name = $r["email"];
            $field4name = $r["is_expired"];
            // $field5name = $r["create_at"]; 
            $field5name = $r["jpeg_info"];
            echo '<tr> 
                  <td>' . $field1name . '</td> 
                  <td>' . $field2name . '</td> 
                  <td>' . $field3name . '</td> 
                  <td>' . $field4name . '</td> 
                  <td><a href = ' . $field5name . ' target = "_blank">
                        <img src=' . $field5name . '  height="100" width="100">
                  </td> //<------------------- i am stuck here
                   </tr>';
        }
        $result->free();
    } else {
        echo '<FONT COLOR="RED" SIZE="5"> NO RESULTS FOUND </FONT>';
    }
}
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bit of information for you [`<font>` is  Obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font#:~:text=The%20HTML%20Font%20Element%20%28%3Cfont%3E%29%20defines%20the%20font,related%20to%20styling%20only%2C%20then%20obsoleted%20in%20HTML5.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a little test in the code to see if the field in question is empty. Not sure what empty is to you so I assumed `''`

```
if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $r) {
        $field1name = $r["id"];
        $field2name = $r["otp"];
        $field3name = $r["email"];
        $field4name = $r["is_expired"];
        // $field5name = $r["create_at"]; 
        $field5name = $r["jpeg_info"];

        if ( $field5name == '' ) {
            $img = 'default.png';
        } else {
            $img = $field5name;
        }

        echo "<tr> 
              <td>$field1name</td> 
              <td>$field2name</td> 
              <td>$field3name</td> 
              <td>$field4name</td>";
              <td>
                <a href='$img' target='_blank'>
                    <img src='$img' height='100' width='100'>
                </a>
               </td>
            </tr>";
    }
}
```